# Retrieve result of nose test case and use in teardown

Tags: python, nose

In nose, the teardown runs regardless if setup has completed successfully or the status of the test run.

I want to perform a task in teardown that is only executed if the test that just ran failed. Is there an easy way to retrieve the result of each individual test case and pass it to the teardown method to be interpreted?

```
class TestMyProgram:
    def setup(self):
        # setup code here

    def teardown(self):
        # teardown code here

        # run this code if test failed
        if test_result == 'FAIL':
            # do something    

    def test_one(self):
        # example test placeholder 
        pass

    def test_two(self):
        # example test placeholder 
        pass
```

Comment: Have you tried checking `self._outcome.errors` in `teardown` method? If it's an empty list, it's a pass. Otherwise it will contain exception type (i.e. `AssertionError` for test fail, any other for test error).

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the state of the test, and pass it on to your teardown method. The state of the test is within nose code: you cannot access without writing a nose plugin. But even with plugin, you would have to write a custom rig to pass on the state to the teardown method. But if you are willing to break the structure of the code a little bit to accommodate your request, you might be able to do something like this:

```
def special_trardown(self, state):
    # only state specific logic goes here
    print state

def test_one_with_passing_state(self):
    try:
        test_one(self)
    except AssertionError as err:
        test_result = "FAIL"
        self.special_teardown(test_result)
        raise
```

Its not perfect, but it makes the flow of events obvious to other people looking at your tests. You can also wrap it up as decorator / context manager for more syntactic sugar.

Comment: I like this. I have tried creating a decorator but it doesn't seem to behave the same when creating it within the test class. Is it possible you can provide an example of creating one in this context?